# Complex Regex : how to don't match reserved word after //

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making a webcode editor, I'm working on the text markup so I wrote this regex :  `/\b(?:abstract|arguments|boolean|break|byte|case|catch|char|const|class|continue|debugger|default|delete|do|double|else|enum|eval|export|extends|false|final|finally|float|for|function|goto|if|implements|import|in|instanceof|int|interface|let|long|native|new|null|package|private|protected|public|return|short|static|super|switch|synchronized|this|throw|throws|transient|true|try|typeof|var|void|volatile|while|with|yield|alert|all|anchor|anchors|area|assign|blur|button|checkbox|clearInterval|clearTimeout|clientInformation|close|closed|confirm|constructor|crypto|decodeURI|decodeURIComponent|defaultStatus|document|element|elements|embed|embeds|encodeURI|encodeURIComponent|escape|event|fileUpload|focus|form|forms|frame|innerHeight|innerWidth|layer|layers|link|location|mimeTypes|navigate|navigator|frames|frameRate|hidden|history|image|images|offscreenBuffering|open|opener|option|outerHeight|outerWidth|packages|pageXOffset|pageYOffset|parent|parseFloat|parseInt|password|pkcs11|plugin|prompt|propertyIsEnum|radio|reset|screenX|screenY|scroll|secure|select|self|setInterval|setTimeout|status|submit|taint|text|textarea|top|unescape|untaint|window|onblur|onclick|onerror|onfocus|onkeydown|onkeypress|onkeyup|onmouseover|onload|onmouseup|onmousedown|onsubmit)\b(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)(?![^<]*>)(?![^\/*]*\*\/)/gm`

This the group of reserved words

`/\b(?:abstract|arguments|boolean|break|byte|case|catch|char|const|class|continue|debugger|default|delete|do|double|else|enum|eval|export|extends|false|final|finally|float|for|function|goto|if|implements|import|in|instanceof|int|interface|let|long|native|new|null|package|private|protected|public|return|short|static|super|switch|synchronized|this|throw|throws|transient|true|try|typeof|var|void|volatile|while|with|yield|alert|all|anchor|anchors|area|assign|blur|button|checkbox|clearInterval|clearTimeout|clientInformation|close|closed|confirm|constructor|crypto|decodeURI|decodeURIComponent|defaultStatus|document|element|elements|embed|embeds|encodeURI|encodeURIComponent|escape|event|fileUpload|focus|form|forms|frame|innerHeight|innerWidth|layer|layers|link|location|mimeTypes|navigate|navigator|frames|frameRate|hidden|history|image|images|offscreenBuffering|open|opener|option|outerHeight|outerWidth|packages|pageXOffset|pageYOffset|parent|parseFloat|parseInt|password|pkcs11|plugin|prompt|propertyIsEnum|radio|reset|screenX|screenY|scroll|secure|select|self|setInterval|setTimeout|status|submit|taint|text|textarea|top|unescape|untaint|window|onblur|onclick|onerror|onfocus|onkeydown|onkeypress|onkeyup|onmouseover|onload|onmouseup|onmousedown|onsubmit)\b`

This skip markup if in double quotes

`(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)`

This skip markup if in single quotes

`(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)`

This skip markup if in a tag <>

`(?![^<]*>)`

This skip markup if in a comment /* */

`(?![^\/*]*\*\/)`

Now I'm stuck on the last piece of cake, I need to skip markup if in a comment // [single line]

`(?!\/\/[\w\s\'\"][^\n]*)|(?!\/\/)`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use the same way I explained you. And please stop to use this kind of tests `(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$))` that are totally inefficient (take a look at the regex101.com debugger).

Comment: I'm working on it but there's somenthing that I'm missing

Comment: OMG...my eyes are bleeding!

Comment: it's the same: `/(quotedstrings|comments|allotherthingsIwanttoavoid)|target/`

Comment: It sounds like you need a to write a parser.  Regex is not the right tool for this job especially if you are using a markup style language.  Markup languages, such as HTML/XML, etc are NOT regular languages therefore Regular Expressions should not be used.

Comment: An other thing, when you have a giant alternation, sort all words and put the first letter in factor to reduce the regex engine work: `\b(?:a(?:bstract|rguments)|b(?:oolean|reak|yte)|c(?:...`

Comment: @JNYRanger: please stop to repeat the false argument about `regular languages` that is only pertinent in a computer science context. Tools currently called regex are different than regular expression in computer science and are able to parse things that are not regular at all.

Comment: Thanks Casimir you should be my professor, my regex is the way he show me, now I'll try with your advice to write it again however `(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$))` works in regex101 [if you use the total regex It doesnt match reserved word in single and double quote]

Comment: @Casimir Well considering I'm a computer scientist I'm going to stick to it since it's not exactly a false statement, but instead is a generalization.  Of course they can be used to extract data from strings that are in a non-regular language, however it is inefficient to do so especially when you need to have an expression that looks like OP's.  Writing a parser is a great exercise in programming and is far more efficient than this method.

Comment: @JNYRanger maybe it's true that a parser is a best way to solve my problem, in the other hand I miss the last regex to finish my project and cacth my degree, I know it's sound lazy but I'm almost sure that I'll rewrite soon all the code of this project

Comment: Good luck on your degree & finishing up the project!  Writing a parser is a great exercise and I recommend it to anyone who wants to be a better programmer.

Comment: @JNYRanger thanks, I'm still working on it, I hope to find soon the solution

Comment: Once you get that working, good luck maintaining it.

Comment: @torazaburo what do you mean?

Comment: I mean it's unreadable, unmaintainable, and unextendible.

Comment: @torazaburo of course I'm not a wizard but if you want teach me something show me the right way please

Comment: The right way, as already suggested in an answer, is to use a parser.

Comment: Maybe my skills are not enough to understand

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not to use a regex for this kind of parsing job. Since you are building something in Javascript, you can use [jison](https://zaach.github.io/jison/) to convert a grammar that you design into a working javascript function that will parse text according to your grammar.

Answer (score 0):

if you are curious this is my solution, please let me know if your eyes are bleeding or if it is a good solution :

```
//finding the string that I need to manipulate 

regcomment2 =/(\/\/[\w\s\'\"][^\n]*)|(\/\/)/gm; 

//this the loop to find and replace

var str = finale.match(regcomment2);
    if(finale.match(regcomment2)){
        str = str.toString();
        var arr = str.split(",");
        var arrcheck = str.split(",");
        var text = "";
        var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    //writing right code 
        arr[i]= arr[i].replace(/(<.*?[^ok]>)/g,"");
        console.log("Commento Split Dopo = " + arr[i]);
        console.log("Commento Arr2 = " + arrcheck[i]);
    //replace original code with right code
        finale = finale.replace(arrcheck[i],arr[i]);

}
```